# My visa expired in 2012 and lived here ever since, this coming May I am going to Washington DC. Can I travel domestically with a valid passport?

Tags: visas, usa, passports, overstaying, minors

My Mexican visa expired in March 2012 and have lived in U.S. ever since and going to school here since kindergarten. I am planning on going to Washington DC on a school trip. Can I go showing a valid passport?

Can I travel within the country with a Mexican Citzen ID if my mom gets the Mexican embassy to process a Mexican ID?

I know it may sound stupid but I am afraid of being seen as immigrant and being deported.

I have no other forms of ID's. Only my Visa. My mom wants to go to the Mexican Embassy place and try to get me a passport because we will be visiting the White House and you need an American form of identification and well, I wasn't born in the U.S. or other U.S. territories.

Comment: Did you mean your US visa expired?  Are you out of status (immigration status, that is)?  Are you under 18?  Where do you live?  Partial answer: the only Mexican document you can use to board a plane is a passport -- see https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification.

Comment: Additional partial answer: You don't need an American form of ID for a White House tour, but the only Mexican (or other foreign) document you can use for a White House tour is also a passport: https://www.whitehouse.gov/participate/tours-and-events

Comment: My partial answer: _USA_ children are exempted from the Photo ID requirement at the White House. If you are the only non-citizen in the class (and _especially_ if your teachers don't know your family are undocumented), there probably won't be anyone the wiser as the group tour goes through.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While this looks like a duplicate, it seems likely the OP is a minor, or someone posting on behalf of a minor. The TSA rules for ID for minors are different.

> [Children](https://www.tsa.gov/travel/security-screening/identification)
> TSA does not require children under 18 to provide identification when traveling with a companion within the United States. Contact the airline for questions regarding specific ID requirements for travelers under 18.

A school teacher probably fits the "companion" requirement.